# Add/Remover Inputs dinamicamente php

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Estou criando um formulário em que ao preencher, o usuário irá adicionar mais campos dinamicamente, até aí eu já consegui, porem gostaria de separar o valor de cada campo adicionado para enviar os dados separados em PHP, pois todos estão com o parâmetro `name` com `mytext[]`.

Segue abaixo o código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remover</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Adicionar novo campo</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não entendi Leno. Vocẽ quer receber os valores separadamente, mas ao colocar o `myText[]`, no momento do POST, você recebe esse parâmetro como array. Já não basta? Você quer tretar cada campo como um novo valor no post?

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi sua pergunta, é só colocar o valor de x no name.

```
$(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext"'+x+'/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remover '+x+'</a></div>');
        }
    });
```